Anchor Package Registry down?
Is the Anchor Package Registry discontinued or replaced by another registry? I tried visiting https://api.apr.dev with no valid response.

I don't think it's being maintained anymore.
You have an alternative of using the IDL, if a program publishes it.
The CLI command is anchor idl
e.g to fetch the IDL for <program-id> into out-file.json IDL file use,
anchor idl fetch -o <out-file.json> <program-id>

docs: https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/cli#idl
